# Spaces-to-tabs converter, updated version

Tags: beginner, c, io, formatting

I recently posted [Spaces To Tabs Converter](/q/142930) but it had lots of bugs, so I rewrote the code. I wanted to ask, is it good code? I didn't find any bugs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TABVALUE 4
#define ARRAYSIZE 3

void emptyArray(int *a);

int main(void) {
    int c, d, s;
    int savedChars[ARRAYSIZE];
    c = s = d = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            s = 0;
            s++;
            for (int j = 0; j < TABVALUE - 1; j++) {
                d = getchar();
                if (d != EOF) {
                    savedChars[j] = d;
                    savedChars[j + 1] = '\0';
                    if (d == ' ') {
                        s++;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (s == TABVALUE) {
                emptyArray(savedChars);
                putchar('\t');
                s = 0;
            } else {
                putchar(c);
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (savedChars[i] != '\0') {
                        putchar(savedChars[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (c != EOF) putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void emptyArray(int *a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        a[i] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why variables only used within main are not local to main?

Comment: You are right :)  I will make them local.

Comment: But i guess,`#define VARIABLE_NAME ` must be global (or should be) ?? `ARRAYSIZE` must be anyways because i use it in emptyArray.But i am not sure about `TABVALUE`

Comment: Is there some reason why it needs to be defined with the preprocessor instead of, say, a constant local?

Comment: What do you mean ?? I am not sure i understanded.Are you talking about ARRAYSIZE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A chunk of memory that is used to temporarily queue up content before it is eventually flushed is typically called a *buffer*.  A typical variable name would be `buffer` or `buf`.

You defined constants `TABVALUE` and `ARRAYSIZE`.  It looks like `ARRAYSIZE` is dependent on `TABVALUE`, so you shouldn't hard-code both `4` and `3`.  You also shouldn't hard-code `3` in the `for` loop.

The program outline is basically

> ```
> while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
>     if (c == ' ') {
>         /* Huge chunk of buffer manipulation code here... */
>     } else {
>         if (c != EOF) putchar(c);
>     }
> }
> ```

You've already ascertained that `c` is not `EOF` in the `while` loop, so `if (c != EOF)` is pointless.  I would also recommend inverting the test so that there isn't a huge chunk of code before the `else`.  This outline is equivalent to your logic:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c != ' ') {
        putchar(c);
    } else {
        /* Huge chunk of buffer manipulation code here... */
    }
}
```

The first space encountered gets stored as `c`, but subsequent spaces get written to the `savedChars` buffer.  The code would be simpler if you just wrote the first space to the buffer too.

I'm not convinced that you need a `savedChars` buffer, though.  The buffer will only contain a string of spaces, possibly followed by a non-space character at the end.  You should be able to do the job using just the `s` count and the final character `d`.

Comment: Nice Lesson :) I am not sure why is `if(c!=' '){putchar (c)} else{// all of the code}` better than `if(c==' '){//all of the code} else{putchar(c)}`

Comment: And how could i do this without savedChars buffer ? Can you write an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what the purpose of this is

> ```
>         s = 0;
>         s++;
> ```

inside the While loop, especially since you have already set that variable to `0` outside of the loop

> ```
> c = s = d = 0;
> ```

but the main thing that I am thinking is that you want `s` to have a value of `1` before you do anything inside of that if statement.  Instead of giving `s` such a large scope, let's create it inside of that if statement and let it go away when we leave that if statement, so get rid of the declaration outside of the while loop and rewrite the code like this

```
int main(void) {
    int c, d;
    int savedChars[ARRAYSIZE];
    c = d = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            int s = 1;
            //...
```

and then I look further down into the next if statement inside of the while loop and see that you set `s = 0;`  but you don't use `s` after that, by this I mean that the next time we see `s` in the flow of the code, you are actually setting it back to `1` again.  there isn't any need for this declaration.  Get rid of it.

now the code looks like this for your main method

```
int main(void) {
    int c, d;
    int savedChars[ARRAYSIZE];
    c = d = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            int s = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < TABVALUE - 1; j++) {
                d = getchar();
                if (d != EOF) {
                    savedChars[j] = d;
                    savedChars[j + 1] = '\0';
                    if (d == ' ') {
                        s++;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (s == TABVALUE) {
                emptyArray(savedChars);
                putchar('\t');
            } else {
                putchar(c);
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (savedChars[i] != '\0') {
                        putchar(savedChars[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (c != EOF) putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I really think that you should take this blob of code and put it into its own method and then call it from Main instead of putting it all into Main.

maybe like this

```
int main(void)
{
    int savedChars[ARRAYSIZE];
    CodeToRun(savedChars);
}

void CodeToRun(int[] savedChars)
{
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            int s = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < TABVALUE - 1; j++) {
                d = getchar();
                if (d != EOF) {
                    savedChars[j] = d;
                    savedChars[j + 1] = '\0';
                    if (d == ' ') {
                        s++;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (s == TABVALUE) {
                emptyArray(savedChars);
                putchar('\t');
            } else {
                putchar(c);
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (savedChars[i] != '\0') {
                        putchar(savedChars[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (c != EOF) putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

I would obviously change the name of the method to something more meaningful, I would also suggest that you name your variables a little better as well.

Comment: is my syntax wrong?